# Is linear secret sharing over the addittive group of integers modulo $p$ with $p$ non-prime secure?

Tags: secret-sharing, prime-field

In *Maurer, Ueli. "Secure multi-party computation made simple." Discrete Applied Mathematics 154.2 (2006): 370-381.* I have found the following technique for $k$-out-of-$k$ linear secret sharing:

[image: scheme]

And the note regarding the domain says this:

[image: note]

Is using as domain $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (additive group of integers modulo $p$) with $p$ non-prime secure? Does it make any difference if $p$ is prime or not? What is the most general definition for the domain (I do not get exactly the meaning of the note)? My guess is that $p$ can be any integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the most general definition for the domain (I do not get exactly the meaning of the note)? My guess is that $p$ can be any integer.

In short, a domain is the input space. As said the input space can be any domain. Note that the secret $s$ is from the domain, too.

The note simply says that whatever the domain $\mathscr{D}$ is we can simply impose an addition operation on it. Order them, and number them starting from 0. Now, if the number of elements in the domain is $n = |\mathscr{D}|$ then it is equal to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ which is a [cyclic group under addition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicGroup.html).

> Is using as domain $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (additive group of integers modulo $p$) with $p$ non-prime secure?

Yes.

> Does it make any difference if $p$ is prime or not?

It doesn't make any difference. This secret-sharing doesn't need the multiplicative inverses. Any finite group can be safe. All we need is the group operations.

> As Kodlu [mentioned in the comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/86862/is-linear-secret-sharing-over-the-addittive-group-of-integers-modulo-p-with-p/86865#comment190540_86865)

This secret scheme can also be defined on the multiplicative groups where the inverse exists naturally. Take each $s_i$ for $1\leq i\leq k-1$ random from the domain and calculate $$s_k = s \cdot s_1^{-1} \cdot s_2^{-1} \cdots s_{k-1}^{-1}$$

Comment: And this domain can be any finite group, it can even be a multiplicative group, where you could use the multiplication operation to define the shares as $s_i$ for $1\leq i\leq k-1$ and $s_k=s \cdot s_1^{-1} \cdot s_2^{-1} \cdots s_{k-1}^{-1}$.

Comment: I believe $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $p$ prime and both sum and multiplication as operations is required as a domain (so as it is guaranteed that multiplicative inverses exist) if you use this secret sharing scheme as a building block for secure multiplication as defined in the same paper cited above (Section 5.3). Does it make sense?

Comment: @Lorenzo it seems one needs a ring there, I don't see the multiplicative inverse, since $s_i t_j$ is multiplied and shared with the 5.3. Next, all need is the Ring properties.

Comment: Thanks. So, requiring a ring allows to use for example $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with sum and multiplication as operations and $p$ being anything. Instead, requiring a field adds the constraint of $p$ beng a prime, since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ does not guarantee that multiplicative inverses exist when $p$ is not prime. However, since we do not use multiplicative inverses for secure multiplication, the less restrictive domain is a ring (moreover, it may be useful to do not restrict $p$ being a prime, but instead $2^{8l}$ for some integer $l$, if you work with bytes). Does it make sense?

Comment: If you want to work on $Z_p$. For every prime power, there is also a field. 2^{8\ell} is an extension field of $\mathbb{F}_2$, more specifically binary extension field. Yes a ring seems enough.

Comment: So, for example, I may use as a set for the field $\mathbb{Q}_{2^{8l}}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{2^{8l}}$ (rational or real numbers modulo $2^{8l}$) but not $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{8l}}$. Right?

Comment: Can you guarantee that every element has an inverse $\mathbb{R}_{2^{8l}}$? You should concentrate on the question. That makes another post!

Comment: I think so (?). With respect to sum, the inverse of each element $\alpha$ is $-\alpha$, indeed $\alpha - \alpha = 0$. Then, if we consider non-zero elements only, the inverse of  each element $\alpha$ is $-1/\alpha$, indeed $\alpha \times 1/\alpha = 1$.

Comment: what about $1/2^{8 \ell}$?